# PyPDF2 - combine PdfFileWriter and PdfFileMerger to output one PDF file

Tags: python, merge, bookmarks, pypdf

I would like to combine multiple PDF files using PyPDF2.
I would like to use PdfFileWriter with .addPage to add pages from PDF files that do not have bookmarks, and add a bookmark for the first page.
And use PdfFileMerger with .append to merge the PDF files that have bookmarks, in order to retain those bookmarks.

I have tried the below code, but I don't think it's possible to combine PdfFileMerger .append and PdfFileWriter.addPage

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import os

path = "C:/Users/XXXX/Desktop/TEST PYPDF2/"

pdf_files = ['File1.pdf','File2.pdf','File3','File4']

merger = PdfFileMerger() # merge object
output = PdfFileWriter() # open output
bookmark_page = 0
for files in pdf_files:
    input = PdfFileReader(open(files, 'rb')) # open input
    outlines = input.outlines
    if outlines:
        merger.append(path+files)
        #output.appendPagesFromReader(input) - this doesn't retain the bookmarks
        nr_pages = input.getNumPages()
        bookmark_page = bookmark_page + nr_pages
    else: 
        nr_pages = input.getNumPages()
        for page in input.pages:
            output.addPage(page) # insert page
        output.addBookmark(files, bookmark_page, parent=None) # add bookmark
        bookmark_page = bookmark_page + nr_pages

#Save the file
outputStream = open('bindy.pdf', 'wb')
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

Generally, what I want is to add some PDF files and create Bookmarks for the first page on the spot, then in other cases (when the PDF file to add, has already some bookmarks inside) add the PDF file and retain the bookmarks.

If this is possible only by using PdfFileReader.addPage then this will also be helpfull. But I cannot find the code to retain bookmarks.

Edit 1:

I found that this code `output.cloneReaderDocumentRoot(input)` almost does what I want. It adds the PDF file with all the bookmarks, but it adds only that file. It deletes all other added files. Probably it just creates a copy of the PDF file with bookmarks. If this could instead be added to the output containing the other PDF files, this would be sufficient.